# Copy to clipboard using textarea and document.execCommand('copy) is a problem when MUI popovers are open

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, document, execcommand

An MUI Menu (PopOver) is open with a MenuItem for 'Copy to Clipboard' Option. The MenuItem has an `<IconButton>`. The onClick handler for the IconButton invokes `document.execCommand('copy')`.

The code for CopyToClipBoard is as follows
Ref: [How do I copy to the clipboard in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/400212/how-do-i-copy-to-the-clipboard-in-javascript)

```js
function copyTextToClipboard(text) {
  var textArea = document.createElement("textarea");
  textArea.value = text;
  
  // Avoid scrolling to bottom
  textArea.style.top = "0";
  textArea.style.left = "0";
  textArea.style.position = "fixed";

  document.body.appendChild(textArea);
  textArea.focus();
  textArea.select();

  try {
    var successful = document.execCommand('copy');
    var msg = successful ? 'successful' : 'unsuccessful';
    console.log('Fallback: Copying text command was ' + msg);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error('Fallback: Oops, unable to copy', err);
  }

  document.body.removeChild(textArea);
}
```

This snippet worked perfectly in other pages with no React MUI popovers. However, it never worked with a page where an MUI popover was open.

After some googling, I found that the popovers are auto focus.
Ref: [Prevent auto focus of a material-ui popover element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51388205/prevent-auto-focus-of-a-material-ui-popover-element)

The workaround I have now is to temporarily hide the popovers and re-enable them after copying the text to clipboard.

```js
const fallbackCopyTextToClipboard = text => {
  let textArea = document.createElement('textArea');
  textArea.value = text;

  // Avoid scrolling to bottom
  textArea.style.top = '0';
  textArea.style.left = '-9999'; //Hide from view
  textArea.style.position = 'fixed';
  textArea.style['z-index'] = '9999'; //Bring this infront of all possible popovers

  //This is a hack
  //Momentarily hide all popovers to give focus() to the temporary <textarea>
  const allPopOvers = document.getElementsByClassName('MuiPopover-root');
  const openPopOvers = [];
  for (let popover of allPopOvers) {
    if (popover.style.visibility !== 'hidden') {
      openPopOvers.push(popover);
      popover.style.visibility = 'hidden';
    }
  }
  document.body.appendChild(textArea);
  textArea.focus();
  textArea.select();

  let successful = false;
  try {
    successful = document.execCommand('copy');
    //Undo the changes to visible popovers
    openPopOvers.forEach(popover => {
      popover.style.visibility = '';
    });
  } catch (err) {
    logger.error('Fallback: Oops, unable to copy', err);
  }

  document.body.removeChild(textArea);
  return successful;
};
```

If someone has come across the same issue, please suggest a fix that worked for you.

Comment: Today we have the [Clipboard API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Clipboard_API).

Comment: Yeah. But looks like Clipboard API is not available over 'http'. It works on 'https'.

Comment: A good chunk of the newer features require `https`. There's no good reason these days to have a site available via `http`.